# Make the lines hide (logically speaking) in applets

Tags: java

I am developing an application where I draw large number of lines (color is given as black) and update them where I need to remove them from screen.

I thought of making their color to match with the background so that I can make them hide. It seems to be simple and works but in the practical sense I have 10000 points and almost more than 20000 lines to be drawn and as most the line overlap or cross each other it is so disgusting the view.

So I need some kind of function to actually remove those selected lines between two known points from screen. Even I have a problem with the background color I can match the exact background default color of the applets. Can anyone suggest me solution or the color?

Comment: Could you add a screen shot of the problem you are having with the display?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To draw usingbackground color can use http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#getBackground() which returns the background color, this can be set to the graphics object you are painting to.

Use double buffering, first clear the area by making a rectangle using default color :

g.setColor(backgroundColor);
   g.fillRect(0, 0, fullWidth, fullHeight);

and then draw only active lines. So no complicated algorithm, just start from a clean slate and draw only what is required

Refernece
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#setColor(java.awt.Color)

fillRect(int x, int y, int width, int height) on same page

Double buffering is explained here 
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/fullscreen/doublebuf.html

and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4430356/java-how-to-do-double-buffering-in-swing you could make your own image to process off screen